# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource (express server)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I have an express server with the following configuration for CORS headers

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT,  DELETE');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, x-auth-token');
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
  next();
});
```

And I'm getting the following error when I try to send a request to my server from a different IP address.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://money-manager-api-v1.herokuapp.com/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

> POST https://money-manager-api-v1.herokuapp.com/auth net::ERR_FAILED

The error on the server is here

> 2020-10-13T07:11:59.437570+00:00 app[web.1]: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo

> 2020-10-13T07:11:59.452909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/auth" host=money-manager-api-v1.herokuapp.com request_id=9b274fb3-9861-481e-ac68-d52390759b16 fwd="37.252.80.232" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=17010ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https

What could be wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I had the (more/less) same problem with express, so i found somewhere "cors" lib, which could be added with:

https://yarnpkg.com/package/cors

```
    npm i -S cors (or)
    yarn add cors
```

then in your app.js (main) file, you could add:

```
   ...
   const cors = require('cors');
   ...
   ...
   app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I am getting the same error with the cors library

Comment: Hmm, strange... sadly, i haven't use heroku so i don't know if there's maybe a firewall or something that's denying access from localhost, so you can maybe check there?
also, what are you using to call api from frontend?

Comment: With cors library I'm getting this error
`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://money-manager-api-v1.herokuapp.com/auth' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: I am using axios from the frontend `await axios.get(`https://money-manager-api-v1.herokuapp.com/accounts`);`

Comment: thanks for reply. 
hmm, strange really... one more thing, could you paste the code where you require cors lib and use it (app.use(cors()))?

Comment: i had the same problem, where i know it should work, but i wrote 'app.use(cors())' after defining my routes (for some reason), and apparently, it didn't work, so i moved it on top and it worked.. not sure if it's related but it did the trick :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222944/discussion-between-johnny-tee-and-hayk-simonyan).

Comment: `const cors = require('cors');`
`app.use(cors());`

Comment: I tried to use the cors() in various places in server.js but it still doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support. I found a solution. You can see it in the answers.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad you found the solution! :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for the answers. I found a solution.

I don't know why the error message was related to the CORS, but the problem was that in my config file I passed a wrong MongoDB URI (from my localhost instead of MongoDB atlas).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use cors library.

```
const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors());
```

Comment: I tried cors library too and I'm getting the same error